# Invalid procedure call or argument for creating pivot-table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I tried to record my macro using excel 2010 to produce multiple pivottables but as I ran the programme, the errors occurred at this whole chunk of lines as shown below. I have already come across threads where people have already faced similar problem as me and I followed their advices such as adding '  ' at the name of the worksheet at both or either on the SourceData or TableDestination, same error occurred. Furthermore I also tried replacing tabledestination with Sheets(2).range("A3"), change the name of pivottable to different numbers like pivottable100 instead of pivottable1 and also default version to other pivottableversion such as pivottableversion13/15 but to no avail(same type of error still occurs). At this point I have already run out of ideas.

```
    Sub test()

'

'
    Range("B1:D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase,SourceData:= _
        "'Result'!R1C2:R26C4",Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="'Sheet2'!R3C1",TableName:="PivotTable100",DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14 '<-------Error occurs from activework...to xlpivotversion
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotFields("X_position")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotFields("Y_position")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable100").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable100").PivotFields("Vbd"), "Sum of Vbd", xlSum
End Sub
```

Updated code:

```
Sub test()

    Range("B1:D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Sheets.Add

    Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                "'Result'!R1C2:R26C4", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="'Sheet2'!R3C1", _
               TableName:="PivotTable100", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotFields("X_position")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotFields("Y_position")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable100").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable100").PivotFields("Vbd"), "Sum of Vbd", xlSum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical fix here is to split that line up into two.  I don't know why that fixes it, but usually it does.

EDIT: Here's a more robust version

```
Sub tester()

    Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable, rngSrc As Range
    Dim newSht As Worksheet


    Set rngSrc = Sheets("Result").Range("B1").CurrentRegion '<< source data table

    Set newSht = Worksheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                   SourceData:=rngSrc, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=newSht.Range("A3"), _
                   TableName:="PivotTable100", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

End Sub
```

If you have many tables to create then you can use a Sub for that:

```
Sub Tester()

    DoPivotTable Sheets("Result1").Range("B1").CurrentRegion, _
                 Sheets("Table1").Range("A2"), "table1"

    DoPivotTable Sheets("Result2").Range("B1").CurrentRegion, _
                 Sheets("Table2").Range("A2"), "table2"

End Sub

Sub DoPivotTable(rngSrc As Range, tableDest As Range, tableName As String)
    Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                   SourceData:=rngSrc, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=tableDest, _
              tableName:=tableName, DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-Time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: And on which line?

Comment: Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="'Sheet2'!R3C1", _
               TableName:="PivotTable100",DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

Comment: Same exact code works fine for me.  Please update your question with the exact code you're now using.

Comment: You will get that error if you have no Sheet2 in your workbook.

Comment: ah my bad, now it works thanks alot. So since i have to record 12 pivottables at one go , do i have to  Dim PivotCache and PivotTable using different variables 12 times?

Comment: That depends on whether you're using 12 different datatables, or some of the pivottables share the same source data.

Comment: 12 different datatables in this case so i assume i have to dim pivotcache and pivottable 12 times?